# vector variable value on PHP

Tags: php, variables, vector

Well, ths is a really newbie question, but couldn't find the proper keywords to get the answer.

I have a vector variable, $p.

I want to achieve this:

```
$n = 5;

$prev = $p[$n--];
$actual = $p[$n];
$next = $p[$n++];
```

The values i want should be:

```
$prev = 4;
$actual = 5;
$next = 6;
```

Instead of that, i get:

```
$prev = 5;
$actual = 4;
$next = 4;
```

I know i'm missing something, but i couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use increment deincrement operators before the var in this case. Like this `--$n`. This will change the value of $n however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do the math yourself:

```
$prev   = $p[$n - 1];
$actual = $p[$n];
$next   = $p[$n + 1];
```

If you must use increment / decrement operators (for some strange reason), you can use:

```
$prev   = $p[--$n];
$actual = $p[++$n];
$next   = $p[++$n];
```

Note that your original code was failing, as jeremy points out, because increment and decrement operators modify the original value of the variable.

Comment: Would be useful to explain to the OP *why* his code was failing, that is, that he was actually changing the value of the variable.

Comment: Thanks jeremy, added that bit in.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you.

So, if i use the operators against the variable, it changes the value compeltely, not just for that piece of code. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, it changes the value completely.

Comment: @Javi not *all* operators. For example `$n + 3` doesn't modify `$n`. More info on increment/decrement: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: Ok, i'll read about it. I'm just making my firsts steps into php. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

At the first search:

```
$prev = $p[$n--]
```

You are changing the value of n for the next operations, decreasing it by one. In

```
$next = $p[$n++];
```

You are increasing it again so n value is the same as the beginning. You should do what nickb told.

Comment: pre-increment (++$var) , post-increment ($var++) see in detail [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the same variable inline so:

`$n` doesn't stay as 5 when you do `$n++` or `$n--`, you reassign the value to `$n`

`$n--` = 4, so now $n is 4, not 5 so `$n++` is 5, not 6